# Proof of the estimate $\;\| D^{2} u \|_{L^{p}}\sim \| \Delta u \|_{L^{p}}$ when $p>1$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

Let $u\in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. One can integrate by parts twice to discover that 
$$\;\| D^{2} u \|_{L^{2}}= \| \Delta  u \|_{L^{2}}$$

Is the estimate

$$\;\| D^{2} u \|_{L^{p}}\sim \| \Delta  u \|_{L^{p}}$$

true for $p>1$ ?

A reference for this or a hint of the proof would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is true and the method of proof revolves around Littlewood-Paley decomposition. Try looking in Bahouri-Chemin-Danchin's book on harmonic analysis and PDEs.

Comment: @ Giuseppe Negro. I guess you mean Fourier Analysis
and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations. I browsed it, but could not find the estimate. It is probably implicit   in a more sophisticated Besov space estimate, could you kindly locate the chapter ?

Comment: Sure, sorry about not posting it before. What I had in mind is Lemma 2.1, which is not exactly what you need, however.

Comment: See also Terry Tao's "Nonlinear dispersive equations" pag.331. There are some identities for the homogeneous Sobolev spaces that look similar to what you need.

Comment: @ Giuseppe Negro. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The inequality holds true. See Proposition 3 page 72 in Stein's "singular integrals and differentiability properties of functions".

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: See also the [lecture notes by Klainerman](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~seri/homepage/courses/Analysis2011.pdf), section 6 "Calderòn-Zygmund theory" pag.155. Looks like exactly this question is what motivated the study of Calderòn-Zygmund operators in the first place.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro. Thank you for the helpful remarks